# Comparing pitches with digital audio

Tags: signal-processing, pitch

I work on application which will compare musical notes with digital audio. My first idea was analyzes wav file (or sound in real-time) with some polyphonic pitch algorithms and gets notes and chords from this file and subsequently compared with notes in dataset. I went through a lot of pages and it seems to be a lot of hard work because existing implementations and algorithms are mainly/only focus on monophonic sound.

Now, I got the idea to do this in the opposite way. In dataset I have for example note: A4 or better example chord: A4 B4 H4. And my idea is make some wave (or whatever I don't know what) from this note or chord and then compared with piece of digital audio.

Is this good idea? Is it better/harder solution? 
If yes can you recommend me how to do it?

Comment: What note is `H4`? What scale do you work in? Mine goes `CDEFGABC`… so `H` doesn't occur?

Comment: What do you mean by "compared with piece of digital audio"?  Seems to me that the way to find notes would be to get the Fourier transform and pick out the peaks.  You do have to be cognizant of (and basically ignore) harmonics and "beat" frequencies, of course, and that probably takes a bit of "art".

Comment: sorry H is my mistake, simply chord (multiple tones),,,,"compared with piece of digital audio" that I dont will be retrieve information from music but only comapred.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to take the FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) of the waveform: all the notes (and their harmonics) will be present in the signal. You then look for the frequencies that correspond to notes, and there's your solution.

Note - in order to get decent frequency resolution you need a sufficiently long sample, and high enough sample rate. But try it and you will see.

Here are a couple of screen shots of an app called SpectraWave that I took sitting in front of my piano. The first is of middle A (f = 440 Hz as you know):

[image]

and the second is of an A-minor chord (as you can see, my middle finger is a little stronger and the C is showing up as the note with the greatest volume). The harmonics will soon make it hard to see more than just a few notes…

[image]

Comment: So, If I know what notes are in chord and their frequency, for example(Cm:C, E♭, G) and I find these frequencies in signal where I expected in played song, I have solution?

Comment: You have "the beginnings of a solution". Doing this properly is really quite hard - people have spent many many years on this problem. See how far you get with the above - sample length and sample rate are critically important, as is "sub bin estimation" (the actual frequency is most likely between bins so you must interpolate). Have fun!

Comment: I think how ease this process. Let's say that we know frequency of notes and durations of notes, too. We will use only one instrument piano. Is this restriction can ease it?

Comment: Long notes will be much easier to detect than short ones; and staying within one octave will help tremendously too. Remember that in the middle octave, half notes are separated by just a few Hz: Middle C = 261.6 Hz, C# = 277.2 Hz. The difference is just 15 Hz - you need at least 1/15th of a second worth of data to have a shot at distinguishing them. Lower notes are even harder as the difference is smaller. My suggestion - try stuff, see how it works for you. Post updates and more questions once you get going.

Comment: Ok thanks, and can you recommend me some publications or what exactly search at google? because I don't have idea how this problem is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your "solution" most likely makes matching even more difficult, since you will have no idea what waveform to make for each note.  Most musical instruments and voices not only produce waveforms that are significantly different from single sinewaves or any other familiar waveform, but these waveforms evolve over time.  Thus guessing the proper 
 waveform to use for each note for a match is extremely improbable.

Comment: and what about one instrument, e.g. piano?